# Crash when saving new user Parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So when a user logs in/sign up, they are prompted to enter a name and save it. when they press save the new info is sent to parse and stored. My issues is that If i sign up one user give them a name, save, and logout, then sing up a new user, give them a name and press save, the app crashes. I can then rerun the app and save their name again and it works.

I set an exception breakpoint and it breaks on: user.saveInBackground()
This is my code for the save button

Update: I just learned that whenever I change a users name and save then logout, then sign in with a different user and save a new name for them it crashes.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate {

var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

func alertDismiss(title: String, message: String) {
    var alertDismiss = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertDismiss.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alertDismiss, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

var user: PFUser? = PFUser.currentUser()

@IBOutlet weak var locationServiceSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var profileNavigationBar: UINavigationBar!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    profileNavigationBar.delegate = self

    nameTextField.delegate = self
    saveButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    if let user = self.user {
        usernameLabel.text = user.username
        if let name = user["name"] as? String {
            nameTextField.text = name
        }
    } else {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@IBAction func didTapSaveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let user = self.user {
        if nameTextField.text != "" {
            user["name"] = nameTextField.text
            user.saveEventually()
            alertDismiss("Success", message: "New settings saved")
        } else {
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func didTapLogOut(sender: AnyObject) {
    PFUser.logOutInBackgroundWithBlock { error in

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showLoginView", sender: self)
    }
}

func checkSetting(user: PFUser, settingName : String) -> Bool {
    if let value = user[settingName] as? Bool {
        return value
    }
    return false
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.nameTextField.text = PFUser.currentUser()?["name"] as? String
    self.usernameLabel.text = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}
}
```

Comment: What are the details of the crash?

Comment: Nothing comes up in the console. I set a break point and its on the user.saveInBackground()

Comment: Did you create a new user object?  Otherwise you are trying to change the name of an existing user.

Comment: A new user is created. When I sign the new user in they are created in parse, when i hit save after entering their name and it crashes i checked parse and the new user is there with everything but the name. if i run the app again i can enter the name and save successfully

Comment: What I mean is, do you set `self.user=[PFUser user]` somewhere before `didTapSaveButton` is called? Also, assuming `user` *is* a PFUser why aren't you using `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:` ?  And if you disable the exception breakpoint or step past the exception breakpoint you should get a message from Parse as to what went wrong

Comment: No I don't ill add that and see how that affects it. Im a little confused on why I would use signUpInBackgroundWithBlock because the user signup/signin is handled with sms verification. At this point they have a username and password, there just entering their name which they can change at any time

Comment: Would it be helpful if I Editied my question to include entire class?

Comment: Ok fair enough, but you still need to allocate a new PFUser object, otherwise you are attempting to update the old user object with a new name (and you are logged out so you don't have permission to do that).  Yes, please add more code

Comment: Ok updated question with full class

Comment: So, the user signup/login is happening in another class?  That makes more sense.  What do you get on the console if you disable the exception breakpoint? You need the error message, otherwise it is just guesswork.  I don't understand why Swift is so bad at giving meaningful exceptions

Comment: Well now I'm really confused. I deleted the exception breakpoint and now the error isn't occurring

Comment: Now it doesn't crash but the second user has to enter and save their name twice for it to actually be saved to parse

Comment: I notice that this code is now calling `saveEventually` rather than `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` -  Try using saveInBackgroundWithBlock and log any error.  Also check for any errors or warnings in the console.

Comment: Alright I changed to saveInBackgroundWithBlock and got: Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp"

Comment: There error doesn't happen to the first user sign in, but after the first user anytime I logout a user and sign in a different user and save a name the error occurs

Comment: It looks like the `loginWithUsername:password:` function hasn't completed successfully before you are attempting to update the user

Comment: Ahh ok, I just tried again and go this error: PFKeychainStore failed to get object for key 'currentUser'. What I don't get is why these errors happen but the name is being updated in Parse

Answer (score 0):

When you deal with PFUsers to avoid crashes you need to do it via cloud code and don't forget to include masterKey. One more thing i noted is in your view controller you are using `user.saveEventually()` followed by `alertDismiss("Success", message: "New settings saved")` which is completely wrong because you are giving the user false information, according to parse saveEventually runs sometime in the future and it doesn't have a completion block so in reality you are just fooling the user in believing that the save was successful.